# Finding paths in a Undirected Graph

Tags: php, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Consider the following graph:

[image: dummy graph]

Represented by the following array structure:

```
$graph = array
(
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array('a'),
    'c' => array('a', 'b'),
    'd' => array('a'),
    'e' => array('d'),
    'f' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    'g' => array('d'),
    'h' => array('c'),
    'i' => array('c', 'g'),
    'j' => array(),
);
```

What is the most efficient algorithm to find *all* paths (not just the shortest one) from node X to node Y *in either direction without repeating nodes*? For instance, the paths that lead from node `C` to node `A` are:

```
C --> A
C --> B --> A
C --> F --> A
C --> F --> B --> A
C --> F --> D --> A
C --> I --> G --> D --> A
```

Finding all the paths using the parent nodes of node `X` (`A` and `B`, in the example for node `C`) is trivial, but I am having a really hard time traversing the nodes in a descendant / hybrid direction.

Can someone help me out?

---

**UPDATE**: Following @JackManey advice, I tried to port [IDDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) (Iterative Deepening Depth-First Search) based on the Wikipedia pseudo-code and this is more or less what my code looks like:

```
$graph = directed2Undirected($graph);

function IDDFS($root, $goal) {
    $depth = 0;

    while ($depth <= 2) { // 2 is hard-coded for now
        $result = DLS($root, $goal, $depth);

        if ($result !== false) {
            return $result;
        }

        $depth++;
    }
}

function DLS($node, $goal, $depth) {
    global $graph;

    if (($depth >= 0) && ($node == $goal)) {
        return $node;
    }

    else if ($depth > 0) {
        foreach (expand($node, $graph) as $child) {
            return DLS($child, $goal, $depth - 1);
        }
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here are the helper functions used by it:

```
function directed2Undirected($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $data[$value][] = $key;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

function expand($id, $data, $depth = 0) {
    while (--$depth >= 0) {
        $id = flatten(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip((array) $id)));
    }

    return array_unique(flatten(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip((array) $id))));
}

function flatten($data) {
    $result = array();

    if (is_array($data) === true) {
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)) as $value) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Calling the above yields weird or incomplete results:

```
var_dump(IDDFS('c', 'a')); // a -- only 1 path?
var_dump(IDDFS('c', 'd')); // NULL -- can't find this path?!
```

I think I'm overlooking something from the pseudo-code, but I'm not sure what it is.

---

I also tried [this DFS class](http://mirkules.com/blog/?p=20) that was recommended in another question, although it seems to always find *one* path from node X to node Y, I can't get it to return all paths (demo for [`C` -> `A`](http://codepad.org/SMnt87yi) and [`C` -> `D`](http://codepad.org/opySDEmm)).

---

Since I don't need to know the path actually taken, only *how many paths exist that require `n` number of steps* to get from node X to node Y, I came up with this function (uses `directed2Undirected` above):

```
$graph = directed2Undirected($graph);

function Distance($node, $graph, $depth = 0) {
    $result = array();

    if (array_key_exists($node, $graph) === true) {
        $result = array_fill_keys(array_keys($graph), 0);

        foreach (expand($node, $graph, $depth - 1) as $child) {
            if (strcmp($node, $child) !== 0) {
                $result[$child] += $depth;
            }
        }

        $result[$node] = -1;
    }

    return $result;
}

function expand($id, $data, $depth = 0) {
    while (--$depth >= 0) {
        $id = flatten(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip((array) $id)));
    }

    // no array_unique() now!
    return flatten(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip((array) $id)));
}
```

For [`Distance('c', $graph, 0)`](http://codepad.org/GlJhDMFy), [`Distance('c', $graph, 1)`](http://codepad.org/8zsGX4tq) and [`Distance('c', $graph, 2)`](http://codepad.org/1QQk7xyR) this correctly returns the sum of the distance between `C` and any other node. The problem is, with [`Distance('c', $graph, 3)`](http://codepad.org/kQmlTCBD) ([and](http://codepad.org/txwMMNaL) [higher](http://codepad.org/FLmgZJfN)) it start repeating nodes and returning wrong results:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 12
    [b] => 9
    [c] => -1
    [d] => 9
    [e] => 3
    [f] => 12
    [g] => 3
    [h] => 3
    [i] => 6
    [j] => 0
)
```

The index `a` should only be 6 (3 + 3), since the only ways I can get from `C` to `A` using 3 steps are:

```
C --> F --> B --> A
C --> F --> D --> A
```

Yet, it seems to be considering ***two*** (only?) additional paths that repeat nodes:

```
C --> A --> C --> A
C --> B --> C --> A
C --> F --> C --> A
C --> H --> C --> A
C --> I --> C --> A
```

Of course, index `a` isn't the only wrong one. The problem seems to be `expand()` but I'm not sure how to fix it, `array_diff(expand('c', $graph, $i), expand('c', $graph, $i - 2))` seems to fix this particular error, but that ain't a proper fix... Help?

---

[image: dummy graph again]
<sub><sup>again, so you don't have to scroll</sup></sub>

Comment: Your picture and array show a "directed" graph.  Did you perhaps mean an "unweighted" graph?

Comment: @danielrsmith: Sorry about that, I meant to add arrows in both directions but forgot to do that. To clarify, the graph is **undirected** *and* **unweighted**. =)

Comment: Do you really want *all* paths between two nodes? That can be a pretty large number of paths even with your restriction that a path can contain any given node a max of one time. For example, if the graph was complete(an edge between any two vertices), and had 10 vertices, if im not mistaken there would be 9! paths between any two nodes.

Comment: @chris: In principle, yes -- but I'll be limiting the distance from the origin node to a maximum of 3 steps or so (depending on how fast it will perform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can do a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), although neither one is superior to the other (since it's easy to come up with examples for which one is superior to the other).

**Edit:**  Upon rereading the question and thinking a bit, since you want all paths from `C` to `A`, a DFS starting at `C` would probably make the most sense.  Along the way, you'd have to store sequences of edges and throw sequences away if they don't end up at `A`.

Comment: I've read about the two, from my understanding DFS has more problems with repeating nodes / infinite loops. I tried implementing BFS using the Wikipedia pseudo-code but I couldn't generate the results I was looking for, perhaps I've missed something. I've also searched on literateprograms.org and http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Breadth-First_Search for concrete implementations, but the description is a bit vague.

Comment: I've since lost my BFS implementation, but I'll have my go at it again and I'll post the results here. Meanwhile, if you know of any resources that would allow me to comprehend BFS better, please do tell. =)

Comment: @AlixAxel - Actually, upon some reflection, a depth-first search is probably what you need.  Take a look at the edit above.

Comment: I tried a bunch of stuff and I still didn't manage to crack this, do you mind having a look at my update?

Answer (score 0):

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin','r');
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin','w');

```
fscanf(STDIN,"%d\n",$n);
fscanf(STDIN,"%d\n",$e);
$graph = array();


for ($i = 0;$i<$n; $i++)
{
    $graph[$i] = array();
}


for ($i = 0;$i<$e; $i++)
{
    fscanf(STDIN,"%s%s",$x,$y);
    $row = ord($x[0]) - ord('A');
    $row = ord($y[0]) - ord('A');
    echo $row." ".$col;

    $graph[$row][$col] = 1;
    $graph[$col][$row] = 1;
}

for ($i = 0;$i <$n; $i++)
{
    for ($j= 0;$j<$n ;$j++)
    {
      if ($graph[$i][$j]==1)
      {
          echo"1 ";
      }
      else{
        echo"0 "; 
      }
      echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Welcome and please always add Explanation of your code when answering a question. You can edit your post and add more information.